# How to set registry keys on a service fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to enable my service fabric cluster to run in FIPS mode, which requires a registry key. I can't any guides or info on how to do so. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom script extension, or powershell dsc extension to achieve that. there are plenty examples online.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows

They will allow you to run your code on the SF nodes. Really hard to give more concrete answer since you do not specify how you prefer to achieve it